# remove last defined css style with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Suppose I have the following css styles

```
.someclass{
background: red !important;
}
.someclass{
background: blue !important;
}
```

Now with jquery is it possible to remove lastly defined style in the stylesheet so that who ever write `.someclass` in the new line that background can't be changed.

Comment: Why you want to do that with jQuery which you can do it with CSS only? - @C-Link

Comment: If I do it with jquery then afterwards if anyone change the css that can't be changed.

Comment: I am not getting your purpose as to why you want to do this, but this is simply creating an unnecessary workaround. - @C-Link

Comment: Why not just change the order you include the stylesheets? Split the hard-coded, most important one into a separate file from the one that people can change, then simply include your important one after the changeable one

Answer (score 2):

No but you can add a new style which will override the previous one.

```
$('.someclass').css("cssText", "background: red !important;");
```

Since you have declared important in your css, you will need to pass over this argument when setting it in your jquery.

Hope this helps

Comment: what's the cssText? I've never seen like that.

Comment: It replaces the inline style tag and in this case allows you to pass over a third arguement. Its not well documented, I stumbled upon it on a project not long ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the current class and add a new one with the whatever style you want.

```
$( identifier ).removeClass("someclass");
$( identifier ).addClass("newclass");
```

And in css file you can add:

```
.newclass{
  background: red !important;
 }
```

I hope this it will be usefull to you

Comment: This is not what he asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can write  $('.somebody').css('background','red') in Js file.

Comment: This wont override the !important which is set in the CSS. See my answer which passes over the !important argument